# How to determine when a non-running Linux system was last booted?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, date

I have several Linux distributions installed on my PC (13 at last count) and I would like to know how I can find when I last booted each of them. Preferably as a list, like on one line when I last booted my Debian installation, one another line when I last booted my Gentoo install, on another line when I last booted my PCLinuxOS install, *etc.* I suppose I can check when the last edit to their files was made (as a way of testing when they were last started) but as I chroot into them regularly to update them (using their package manager) I thought this may not be an accurate way of checking.

Comment: `last /the/chroot/var/log/wtmp` perhaps? there may be a `reboot` line in there

Comment: Gives me a ridiculous time for my Arch and Gentoo system. I booted them less than an hour ago yet they're giving me the exact same output for that command `wtmp begins Sun Dec 17 19:28:53 2017`.

Comment: wtmp tells you about logins, not boot time. `/bar/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kernel` might be more useful.  Looking at the modification time might be enough.

Comment: Sorry mate but unfortunately neither file you mentioned exists (and yes after correcting for your bar typo) for any of my installed systems.

Comment: on installed systems you can use who -b  or w to know how long & when system is marked "up & running"  but this will not inform you on boot request time

Comment: look at the date of the directory /var/log *before* booting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sure thing that each instance wrote more than one line of dmesg / syslog to `/var/log/*` files at boot time. Filenames like `messages` and `syslog` are pretty popular, but YMWV. Mount the relevant partition RO, and go grep'ing for "kernel:" bootup messages. As a bonus, the syslog output will reveal the configured uname hostname of each instance. Looking for the string "Linux version" would be a good starting point, as it tends to appear early in the boot sequence.